# Scraping Data from a table with Scrapy

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I'm trying out Scrapy for first time. After doing fair bit of research I got the basics. Now I was trying to get data of a table. It isn't working. Check below for source codes.

**items.py**

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class Digi(Item):

    sl = Field()
    player_name = Field()
    dismissal_info = Field()
    bowler_name = Field()
    runs_scored = Field()
    balls_faced = Field()
    minutes_played = Field()
    fours = Field()
    sixes = Field() 
    strike_rate = Field()
```

**digicric.py**

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from crawler01.items import Digi

class DmozSpider(Spider):
    name = "digicric"
    allowed_domains = ["digicricket.marssil.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://digicricket.marssil.com/match/MatchData.aspx?op=2&match=1250"]

    def parse(self, response):

        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_divData"]/table[3]/tr')
        items = []

        for site in sites:
            item = Digi()
            item['sl'] = sel.xpath('td/text()').extract()
            item['player_name'] = sel.xpath('td/a/text()').extract()
            item['dismissal_info'] = sel.xpath('td/text()').extract()
            item['bowler_name'] = sel.xpath('td/text()').extract()
            item['runs_scored'] = sel.xpath('td/text()').extract()
            item['balls_faced'] = sel.xpath('td/text()').extract()
            item['minutes_played'] = sel.xpath('td/text()').extract()
            item['fours'] = sel.xpath('td/text()').extract()
            item['sixes'] = sel.xpath('td/text()').extract()
            item['strike_rate'] = sel.xpath('td/text()').extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key problem is that you are using `sel` inside the loop. The other key problem is that your XPath expressions point to the `td` element while you need to get `td` elements by index and correlate it with the `item` fields.

Working solution:

```
def parse(self, response):
    sites = response.xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_divData"]/table[3]/tr')[1:-2]

    for site in sites:
        item = Digi()
        item['sl'] = site.xpath('td[1]/text()').extract()
        item['player_name'] = site.xpath('td[2]/a/text()').extract()
        item['dismissal_info'] = site.xpath('td[3]/text()').extract()
        item['bowler_name'] = site.xpath('td[4]/text()').extract()
        item['runs_scored'] = site.xpath('td[5]/b/text()').extract()
        item['balls_faced'] = site.xpath('td[6]/text()').extract()
        item['minutes_played'] = site.xpath('td[7]/text()').extract()
        item['fours'] = site.xpath('td[8]/text()').extract()
        item['sixes'] = site.xpath('td[9]/text()').extract()
        item['strike_rate'] = site.xpath('td[10]/text()').extract()
        yield item
```

It correctly outputs 11 item instances.

Comment: It is showing error. Here is the screenshot of the error
[error screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/HPh5lia.png)
And here is the codes:
[link](http://i.imgur.com/InxV60O.png)
[link](http://i.imgur.com/XtKyOkr.png)

Comment: @TanzibHossainNirjhor strange, worked for me. What Scrapy version are you using?

Comment: [ Scrapy 0.24.5 ] [ Python 2.7.9 ] [ PIP 6.0.8 ] [ Windows 8.1 ]

Comment: @TanzibHossainNirjhor check if `parse()` is indented properly.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran your code with Scrapy and it worked perfectly. What exactly was not working for you?

P.S. This should be a comment but I don't have enough reputation yet... I will edit/close the answer accordingly if necessary.

EDIT:

I think you should to do `yield item` at the end of each loop instead of `return item`. The rest of your code should be fine.

Here is an example from the [Scrapy documentaion](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html):

```
import scrapy
from myproject.items import MyItem

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example.com'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.example.com/1.html',
        'http://www.example.com/2.html',
        'http://www.example.com/3.html',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for h3 in response.xpath('//h3').extract():
            yield MyItem(title=h3)

        for url in response.xpath('//a/@href').extract():
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: The problem is the loop in happening, but no data is being crawled into the item.